# Saving values in Shiny which update and are available for select in the same session

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

so the issue i am having is as follows: I am trying to create a shiny dashboard where users can enter data which is saved to a global variable (to be accessed at later logins) and is also immediately available in the same working session.

I've put together a simple example of what i'm trying to achieve, please run the first part of code which is blocked out to set up the global variable we want to save data to. Then run the second part of the code.

I am able to save data to the global variable which is accessible in the dashboard in later sessions it's just not available in the same session.

The way the dashboard works is a user will enter their name, save it to the global variable, then everything on the variable will be available for selection in the list.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)

#RUN THIS CODE FIRST
#setwd(choose.dir())
#Namelist <- NULL
#Namelist <- as.list(Namelist)
#save(Namelist,file = "Namelist.rdata")

#RUN THIS CODE SECOND
load("Namelist.rdata")

values <- reactiveValues()
values$Namelist <- Namelist

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    textInput("text","Enter Name"),
    actionButton("save","Save Text"),
    selectInput("name","Select Name",choices=names(Namelist), multiple = FALSE, selected = names(Namelist))
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){
  observeEvent(input$save,{
    Namelist <- values$Namelist
    Name <- input$text
    Namelist[[length(Namelist)+1]] <- Name
    names(Namelist)[length(Namelist)] <- as.character(Name)
    save(Namelist, file = "Namelist.rdata")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: ok we dont have access to your `NameList.rdata`, so we can only guess. Try to define your `reactiveValue()` in your `server <- function(input,output, session)` that could help,...

Comment: the Namelist.Rdata is just an empty list: #setwd(choose.dir())
#Namelist <- NULL
#Namelist <- as.list(Namelist)
#save(Namelist,file = "Namelist.rdata")

Comment: does the solution below work for you?